# adb command trigger on linux using java

Tags: java, linux, adb

I have to run an intent broadcast on my emulator device running on Linux platform. I am using java for coding. below is the line of code i have written in an attempt to attain the same

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"adb", "shell", "am", "broadcast", "-a", "\"<package name>.SWITCH_ENVIRONMENT\"", "--es ENVIRONMENT", "\""+Build+"\"" });
Thread.sleep(200);
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = "";
while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
   System.out.println(line+"\n");
}
```

But all I get in my console output is:

cannot bind `tcp:5037`

`adb` server is out of date.  killing...

Comment: your problem has nothing to do with your `java` code. make sure that your  `adb` command works from the command line first

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the suggestion. Fixed this. The issue was the presence of two adb binaries on the Linux machine

Answer (score 0):

> adb server is out of date. killing...

Probably there are two `adb` binary. java program might be taking `adb` from different location other than your emulator. you can check how many adb binaries are in your PC.

try below in your terminal and maintain only one adb binary -

`which adb` - To see from which folder currently `adb` is running.

`locate adb`, and remove `adb` other than `adb` from your sdk folder.